# what does Broken exactly mean in the Azure profiler?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I was looking into Azure Application Insight but unable to find anything about BROKEN meaning.What is the meaning of BROKEN?

[image]

Comment: This is a speculation, but I think "BROKEN" means that some methods were executing during the specified time range but started or finished outside of it. In this case the method would have used some CPU time but it can't be profiled because only part of it is contained within selected time range.